# Carrierwave and MiniMagick - images not uploading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, minimagick

I have an app running on Nitrous.io with a Ruby 2 and Rails 4.0 setup.

I have carrierwave and Mini_magick gems installed but still my images don't seem to be uploading.

I have the following setup:

profile_uploader.rb

```
class ProfileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :file

  def store_dir
      "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

end
```

Model - list.rb

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :profile, ProfileUploader
end
```

New.html.haml

```
= form_for @list, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|

  .field
    = f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name

  .field
    = f.label :telephone
    = f.text_field :telephone

  .field
    = f.label :Profile_image
    = f.file_field :profile 
    = f.hidden_field :profile_cache

  = f.submit

= link_to 'Back', lists_path
```

Really can't work out why this isn't working as I believe everything is setup correctly. Any help people can offer would be great!

Answer (score 2):

So it turns out in my controller I had the following:

```
def create
    @list = List.new(list_params)
    if @list.save
      redirect_to lists_path
    else
      render 'lists#new'
    end
end
....

def list_params
    params.require(:list).permit(:name, :telephone)
end
```

As soon as I added `:profile` to the list_params definition it started working :)